# SQL CASE set into multiple variable inside select statement

Tags: sql, case

Hi I'm not good at sql and I've been wondering if this is possible or any work around solution:

from this:

```
SELECT name,
     (CASE
        WHEN @idparam =  tmp.id THEN
            tmp.total_number_subjects
        ELSE
            0
      END) AS TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER,
      (CASE
        WHEN @idparam =  tmp.id THEN
            tmp.total_number_subjects
        ELSE
            0
      END) AS COPY_TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER
      FROM #table tmp
```

to looking like this:

```
SELECT name,
     (CASE
        WHEN @idparam =  tmp.id THEN
            tmp.total_number_subjects
        ELSE
            0
      END) AS (TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER,COPY_TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER)
      FROM #table tmp
```

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to achieve at the end there? Especially `AS (TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER,COPY_TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER)`. This is incorrect syntax for sure. What are you trying to "workaround" and why? The first sql seems to be correct syntax. You should provide table schema(s) as well as expected results if you want any proper assistance and then elaborate on exactly what it is that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it  with a nested select like in the following example

```
select Name
     , x as TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER
     , x as COPY_TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER 
  from (
    SELECT name,
          (CASE
             WHEN @idparam =  tmp.id THEN
                 tmp.total_number_subjects
           ELSE
              0
           END) AS x
      FROM #table tmp
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems want to decline the repetition of `case` expression :

```
SELECT tmp.Name, t.subject_number AS TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER, 
       t.subject_number AS COPY_TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER
FROM #table tmp CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (CASE WHEN @idparam = tmp.id 
                    THEN tmp.total_number_subjects ELSE 0
               END)
     ) t (subject_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can eliminate the `case` and use this code:

```
SELECT name,
       s.TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER,
       s.COPY_TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER
FROM #table t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT tmp.total_number_subjects as TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER, tmp.total_number_subjects as COPY_TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER
      WHERE @idparam = tmp.id 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT tmp.total_number_subjects as TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER, tmp.total_number_subjects as COPY_TOTAL_SUBJECT_NUMBER
      WHERE @idparam <> tmp.id   -- might need to take NULL into account
     ) s;
```

With this approach you can have as many different values as you would like, with complicated expressions.